# Refactor many duplicate ProducesResponseType to make it DRY

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

Currently, I have 20 endpoints with same code with these 3 lines of `ProducesResponseType`. I am using .NET Core 3.1 and Swagger. How do I refactor my code to make it DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)?

```
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(SuccessResponse))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, Type = typeof(ErrorResponse))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, Type = typeof(ErrorResponse))]
public IActionResult Controller1(){
 // code removed for brevity
}

[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(SuccessResponse))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, Type = typeof(ErrorResponse))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, Type = typeof(ErrorResponse))]
public IActionResult Controller2(){
 // code removed for brevity
}

[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(SuccessResponse))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, Type = typeof(ErrorResponse))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, Type = typeof(ErrorResponse))]
public IActionResult Controller3(){
 // code removed for brevity
}
```

Comment: I don't no if custom attributes could lead to your goal or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Core supports [Web API Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/conventions?view=aspnetcore-5.0), which:

> ...includes a way to extract common API documentation and apply it to multiple actions, controllers, or all controllers within an assembly.

The first step is to create a `static class`, with methods that define the conventions:

```
public static class SomeApiConvention
{
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(SuccessResponse))]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, Type = typeof(ErrorResponse))]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, Type = typeof(ErrorResponse))]
    [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Any)]
    public static void Default() { }
}
```

The name of the class isn't important, but the name of the method can impact how the convention is applied. In the example above, the `[ApiConventionNameMatch]` attribute disables this particular functionality so that the convention is used regardless of the action's method name.

To apply this convention to a controller, use the `[ApiConventionType]` attribute:

```
[ApiConventionType(typeof(SomeApiConvention))]
public class Controller1 : ControllerBase
```

This approach applies the convention to every action the controller defines, because of the `[ApiConventionNameMatch]` configuration already highlighted. Alternatively, if you changed `Default` to something else, e.g. `Get`, and removed the `[ApiConventionType]` attribute, the convention would apply only to the actions named `Get`.

To apply the convention only to a specific action, use the `[ApiConventionMethod]` attribute:

```
[ApiConventionMethod(typeof(SomeApiConvention), nameof(SomeApiConvention.Default))]
public IActionResult Action1()
```

This approach expects both the `Type` of the convention class and the name of the method to apply.

---

There's a lot more to this feature, which is described in the docs I've already mentioned. I won't replicate all of that here, as I hope the information included above is enough to get you to where you want to be.